# Set position of one tic number in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm currently plotting a several plot one side to side. Since there are lots of graphs, I need to waste as little space as possible. At the moment I have this situation:

[image: plot I have]

I want to "right align" the number associated to the first tic in the X axis and "left align" the number associated to the last tic in the X axis. In this way I can achieve the following (saving some pixels):

[image: plot I want to achieve]

At the moment both tics and number are set automatically. Is there a way to achieve this in gnuplot? I know you can set via `xtics left|center|right` the alignment of all the values in the axis.

Regardless of my objective to achieve plot compactness (this may be a XY problem), the question still remains: **but does exist a method to manually set the alignment of a particular tic**?

Thanks for any kind reply

NOTE: I didn't wrie the version of gnuplot since using a particular version is not a requirement to solve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not very clean solution, but you could for example first define the tics globally and then manually "override" the particular ticks "of interest":

```
set xr [0:100]
set yr [0:100]

unset key

set xtics 0,20,100
set xtics add ("  0" 0 0)
set xtics add ("100    " 100 0)


plot x w l lc rgb 'dark-red' lw 2
```

unfortunately, it seems that doing something like this:

```
set xtics 0,20,100
set xtics add right ("100" 100 0)
```

affects the alignment of all ticks and not just the added one...

Answer (score 0):

What bugs me in changing the position of only the first and last tic marks is that the space between the labels 20 to 30 won't be the same as 30 to 40 and so on. I've had this problem in the past, and you can play with the number of tics and the range. For example:

```
set xtics 10
set xrange[15:105]
```

or if you really want to stick to the 20:100 range:

```
set xtics 15
set xrange[20:100]
```

You can also add `mxtics` to make it look even prettier. This is not a formal solution by any means, just a nice workaround. Hope it helps.